# Can I use the GUI wallet over SSH?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, remote-access

I SSH into a Linux 16.04.2 LTS box, where I run `monerod` and `monero-wallet-cli` from the command line.  Can I run the GUI similarly?  Do I need to I need to add any args to the `ssh` command?  Do I need to add any args to the `monero-wallet-gui` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to what Moroccan Engineer suggested, if you really want to have the GUI binary running on the remote machine, you could SSH with X forwarding so that you can open graphical applications over SSH, using the -X flag. For more info see here: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely

Answer (score 5):

Just change :

```
ssh XXXXXXX
```

with :

```
ssh -L18081:127.0.0.1:18081 XXXXXXX
```

This means : open a local port 18081, and redirect all messages to `127.0.0.1:18081` in the remote host.

This will be exactly like running `monerod` in your local computer. So just use the default host in `monero-wallet-gui`, which is `127.0.0.1`